# Query to get list of all additions , deletions and modifictaions done in the mysql database in the past

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

My application is AngularJs + RubyOnRails + MySQL. 
 I need to query in rails to list all the changes made in the database in the past ie. Addition, Deletion or Modification made in any table in the database along with the datetime when the change occurred , the action(add/delete/modify) and the details of the changes eg:

### DateTime                 |Action |  Table Name |     User

Mar-21-2016 12:53:49 AM    | ADD      |Activity    |  ari.gunawan

> For table 'Activity' the record with the Record ID 61327 the following
>   changes changes were made.: [EntityRef]='976' , [ContactsRef]='702' ,
>   [EmailCC]='' , [EmailFromName]='' , [EmailFrom]='' ,
>   [ActualDuration]='0' , [ContactName]='Ms Novita' ,
>   [CreatedDate]='NULL' , [CreatedByRef]='NULL' , [AssignedToRef]='33' ,
>   [Comments]='
>
> Yth. Pak Arie,
>
> Mohon bantuannya untuk memposting iklan lowongan
>   kerja untuk salah satu divisi usaha grup sekolah kami. 
>    Materi Iklan terlampir.   Terima
>   kasih, Pak Arie.     Salam
>   Sejawat,   Novita' ,
>   [ContactEmail]='hrdmutiarabunda@gmail.com' , [EmailSubject]='' ,
>   [ActualStartDate]='Mar-21-2016 07:53 AM' ,
>   [ActualCompletedDate]='21-Mar-2016 07:53:00 AM' ,
>   [ContactPhoneNumber]='022 7211200' , [ActivityPriorityRef]='2' ,
>   [LastModifiedDate]='NULL' , [LastModifiedByRef]='NULL' ,
>   [EmailBody]='' , [ActivityTypeRef]='3' , [EmailBCC]='' ,
>   [TempBillAddressCityStateProvZipPostal]='BANDUNG,' ,
>   [ActivityStatusRef]='3' , [FollowUpFromActivityNoRef]='NULL' ,
>   [DueDateStart]='Mar-21-2016 07:53 AM' , [EmailTemplateRef]='NULL' ,
>   [EmailTo]=''

All the tables in the database have the fields created_at,created_by,updated_at,updated_by.

How can I do the above in Rails?

Comment: I recommend you to create a table that will list the events that are happening on your project. Then from that table, you can now retrieve what you want.

Comment: Is it possible to update in two tables simultaneously in rails? Eg: Whenever a record is added to Products model ,  the Product model is updated also the Event table updated for this event that added.

Comment: yup, it's possible

Answer (score 0):

you have to maintain a table with fields created_at,created_by,updated_at,updated_by to store these data with **triggers** for add/delete/modify.

here some example for **triggers** in mssql (***triggers*** are event responders that happens when user do interact with the database, they will trig automatically)

**INSERT**

```
/*
  InsertProductTrigger.sql creates a trigger that fires
  after an INSERT statement is performed on the
  Products table
*/
CREATE TRIGGER InsertProductTrigger 
ON Products
AFTER INSERT
AS
  -- don't return the number of rows affected
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  -- declare an int variable to store the new
  -- ProductID 
  DECLARE @NewProductID int 
  -- get the ProductID of the new row that
  -- was added to the Products table
  SELECT @NewProductID = ProductID 
  FROM inserted
  -- add a row to the ProductAudit table
  INSERT INTO ProductAudit ( Action ) 
VALUES ('Product added with ProductID of ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @NewProductID)  )
```

**UPDATE**

```
/*
  UpdateUnitPriceProductTrigger.sql creates a trigger
  that fires after an UPDATE statement is performed on the
  the UnitPrice column of the Products table.
  If the reduction of the unit price of a product is
  greater than 25% then a row is added to the ProductAudit table
  to audit the change.
*/
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateUnitPriceProductTrigger 
ON Products
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  -- don't return the number of rows affected
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  -- only run the code if the UnitPrice column
  -- was modified
IF UPDATE(UnitPrice)
BEGIN
  -- declare an int variable to store the
  -- ProductID 
  DECLARE @MyProductID int 
  -- declare two money variables to store the
  -- old unit price and the new unit price
  DECLARE @OldUnitPrice money
  DECLARE @NewUnitPrice money
-- declare a float variable to store the price
  -- reduction percentage
  DECLARE @PriceReductionPercentage float
  -- get the ProductID of the row that
  -- was modified from the inserted table
  SELECT @MyProductID = ProductID 
  FROM inserted
  -- get the old unit price from the deleted table
  SELECT @OldUnitPrice = UnitPrice 
  FROM deleted
  WHERE ProductID = @MyProductID 
  -- get the new unit price from the inserted table
  SELECT @NewUnitPrice = UnitPrice 
  FROM inserted
  -- calculate the price reduction percentage
  SET @PriceReductionPercentage =
    ((@OldUnitPrice -@NewUnitPrice) / @OldUnitPrice) * 100
  -- if the price reduction percentage is greater than 25%
  -- then audit the change by adding a row to the PriceAudit table
  IF (@PriceReductionPercentage > 25)
  BEGIN
    -- add a row to the ProductAudit table
    INSERT INTO ProductAudit (Action ) 
VALUES ( 'UnitPrice of ProductID #' +CONVERT(nvarchar, @MyProductID) +
 ' was reduced by ' + CONVERT(nvarchar, @PriceReductionPercentage) + '%' )
    END
  END
```

**DELETE**

```
/*
  DeleteProductTrigger.sql creates a trigger that fires
  after a DELETE statement is performed on the
  Products table
*/
CREATE TRIGGER DeleteProductTrigger 
ON Products
AFTER DELETE
AS
  -- don't return the number of rows affected
  SET NOCOUNT ON
  -- declare an int variable to store the
  -- ProductID 
  DECLARE @NewProductID int 
  -- get the ProductID of the row that
  -- was removed from the Products table
  SELECT @NewProductID = ProductID 
  FROM deleted
  -- add a row to the ProductAudit table
  INSERT INTO ProductAudit (Action) 
VALUES ('Product #' +CONVERT(nvarchar, @NewProductID) +' was removed' )
```